# Query to display Propernoun using SPARQL over dbpedia

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, ontology, dbpedia

How to display all propernoun like Manchester_United_F_C., Arsenel_FC, United_States using SPARQL over DBpedia ?

Comment: Why do you ask ? What do you want to do with that ? It's seems like a desesparate request...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to display *all* propernouns from DBpedia *and only* propernouns, you'll have to manually select the labels that correspond to proper noun and filter out those that don't.

Start with this query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ?label WHERE {
     ?s  rdfs:label  ?label .
 }
```

There are 21,695,594 triples matching this triple pattern, so good luck to figure out which are propernouns, which are not.